How to get the operation history via python?
I would like to know if the user has used bpy.ops.wm.append or bpy.ops.scene.new operations in order to modify properties in my plugin.
Is it possible to somehow get subscribed to these operations when they happens (via msgbus?), or alternatively access some sort of history of all operators used by the user?
Bests

I think what you want is bpy.types.WindowManager.operators. As far as I can tell it keeps a history of the different operators that were used. You may leverage this to peek into the operator history. You can get access to the last used operator by checking the last element in the collection. You can for example keep a parallel list of operators to check which ones have been run since you last checked.
The docs are not really clear about the maximum length of the operator history but since it's an attribute of the window manager I would expect it to be invalidated on UNDO / REDO, SAVE / LOAD and maybe when rendering.
import bpy

# This will give a list of operator history :
print([o.bl_idname for o in bpy.context.window_manager.operators])

def check_operators():
    operator_history = [o.bl_idname for o in bpy.context.window_manager.operators]
    new_operators = operator_history[len(check_operators.operator_cache)::]
    check_operators.operator_cache = operator_history[:]
    print(f"new operators since last call : {new_operators}")
    return 1.0  # Check time interval

check_operators.operator_cache = []

bpy.app.timers.register(check_operators)

Note you can also check which properties the operators have been called with.
import bpy

# This will print a history of operator and their properties :
print(
    [
        [
            o.bl_idname, 
            {p:v for p,v in o.properties.items()}
        ] 
        for o in bpy.context.window_manager.operators
    ]
)


that is awesome! thank you so much, i did not knew this existed

@Fox Cheers. FWIW you can also inspect the properties the operator were called with, see edit to my answer.
